# Do I need to cut stone countertop for kitchen sink?

Tags: kitchen-sink, countertops

I am looking to replace my top mount kitchen sink with another top mount sink that is 5cm bigger on the left-hand side, this only really affects the drying area, and the sink and waste disposal fit into the current void.

My question is can I install the sink (extra 5cm) directly onto the countertop,
or is there some requirement that means I need to cut more of the countertop out?

I feel like it should be okay but wanted some advice as I cannot see people online doing it this way, everyone has perfectly cut holes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the new sink fit in the existing hole in the counter top?

- If so, drop it in, caulk it, adjust (if necessary) and connect the plumbing and enjoy.
- If not, you'll have to enlarge the hole to make it fit.

If you do have to enlarge the hole, you may want to seriously consider hiring someone to do the cutting for you. While you *can* cut a stone countertop yourself, it's not easy, most folk don't have the proper tools, and a screw up here can lead to needing to replace the entire countertop, which probably isn't a top-priority budget item for you today.

There are other questions here about cutting stone countertops, I'd recommend doing some searching to see what's involved.

Comment: Thanks that's what I wanted to know. I wasn't sure you could just caulk it, the sinks do fit into the existing hole so should be grand not to enlarge the countertop.

Comment: @user685590 I'm not sure if there would be any special type of caulk to work with whatever type of stone you have, so you may want to investigate that. I know that some stone countertops are quite porous and prone to staining, so take care not to make a mess.